# React Native: Cannot scroll <ScrollView> when touching anything that does not have `onPress` function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In short: Is ScrollView supposed to scroll only when pressing component that has `onPress` function or is something preventing it working as expected?

I noticed ScrollView works when touching on Buttons or other components with `onPress` function. But when trying to scroll it touching on for example `<Text>` component nothing happens. I noticed this by then adding `onPress` to `<Text>` component (as it has this functionality) and then scrolling works perfectly. Same could be applied to `<View>` components by changing them to `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` with empty onPress:  `onPress={() => { }}`.
But this should not be the case and it increases the workload.

There are tons of question regarding why React Native ScrollView is not working. I tried to found out if this question is answered already but did not come across.

```
"expo": "^43.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in ScrollView there needs to be main child component that has onPress functionality so that it can recognizes touch event.